# Grab Table Name From MySQL Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to just grab one table name so that the table name is included to create an array of dictionary items. This is what my table currently looks like:

```
[
 {
   id: "1",
   track: "Revolution",
   artist: "Lou Yoellin",
   file: "Revolution.mp3"
 },
 {
  id: "2",
  track: "Superstitious",
  artist: "Random Artist",
  file: "Superstitious.mp3"
 }
]
```

I would like to change to add the name of my table, songs, before the array:

```
songs: [
 {
   id: "1",
   track: "Revolution",
   artist: "Lou Yoellin",
   file: "Revolution.mp3"
 },
 {
  id: "2",
  track: "Superstitious",
  artist: "Random Artist",
  file: "Superstitious.mp3"
 }
]
```

I would not like to grab multiple tables but just one. Below is my PHP code. I have a feeling all I need to do is change the SQL command, but I am fairly new to programming and database retrieval.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("x","x","x","x");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 // This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Songs'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs";

// Show all Tables
// $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM myiosapp";

// $sql = "SELECT songs FROM myiosapp.tables";


// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();


    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the name when you output the array:

```
echo json_encode(['songs' => $resultArray]);
```

Comment: that worked. thank you so much! ill accept your answer as correct, in a couple mins when it lets me